# ivy.xml links are broken for sbt debugger in scala

Tags: scala, debugging, sbt

I'm trying to implement [scala-debugger](https://scala-debugger.org/).

I have scala 2.4.3, SBT 1.0, Windows 10 (64bit)

I'm using the SBT plugging.

`addSbtPlugin("org.scala-debugger" % "sbt-scala-debugger" % "1.1.0-M3")`
in the file `~/.sbt/0.1/plugins/plugins.sbt`

Do you know where can I find the `ivy.xml` required to enable sbt debugger for scala?

The status for each link is 404:

```
[warn]  module not found: org.scala-debugger#sbt-scala-debugger;1.1.0-M3
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-debugger/sbt-scala-debugger/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.1.0-M3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-debugger/sbt-scala-debugger/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.1.0-M3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\my_user\.ivy2\local\org.scala-debugger\sbt-scala-debugger\scala_2.12\sbt_1.0\1.1.0-M3\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-debugger/sbt-scala-debugger_2.12_1.0/1.1.0-M3/sbt-scala-debugger-1.1.0-M3.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\my_user\.sbt\preloaded\org.scala-debugger\sbt-scala-debugger\1.1.0-M3\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:/C:/Users/my_user/.sbt/preloaded/org/scala-debugger/sbt-scala-debugger_2.12_1.0/1.1.0-M3/sbt-scala-debugger-1.1.0-M3.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-debugger#sbt-scala-debugger;1.1.0-M3: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          org.scala-debugger:sbt-scala-debugger:1.1.0-M3 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          org.scala-debugger:sbt-scala-debugger:1.1.0-M3 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (C:\Users\my_user\damolina\scala\gl-cost-dept-mapping\project\plugins.sbt#L2-3)
[warn]            +- default:gl-cost-dept-mapping-build:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
```

Comment: How do you add this dependency? Add relevant part of the `build.sbt` or `project/*.sbt` to the question.

Comment: @laughedelic My bad. I updated the question. Thanks for ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin just isn't available for sbt 1:

https://github.com/ensime/scala-debugger/issues/367

You will have to use sbt 0.13 for it or help the maintainers to upgrade to sbt 1 and publish it.

Comment: Yeah I got the same answer from them [here](https://github.com/ensime/scala-debugger/issues/369#issuecomment-524719029) thanks anyway!